# Visual Basic Httpwebresponse Error 404 using LOOP

Tags: vb.net, loops, if-statement, httpwebresponse

im getting error 404 in my httpwebresponse what im doing is that im extracting data from json of a url using a loop each time it does enter a new url ,

so my loop is like this textbox6.text each time it does give a +1 value lets say i started with 550 it continues as 551 552 553 etc if my i reach a number with a url without response the program does give 440 error (crash)i want to make that statment

```
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

to make it into IF statment and if the website doesnt response it should do textbox6.text = textbox6.text +1 else it does nothing

```
    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    Dim uristring As String = ("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + TextBox6.Text + "?api_key=315b4646c080bc576529769498ccc658")
    Dim uri As New Uri(uristring)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Method = "get"
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim read = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim rawresp As String = read.ReadToEnd()
    Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(rawresp)
    Dim imdb_ID = jsonResulttodict.Item("imdb_id")
    TextBox3.Text = imdb_ID
End Sub
```

Comment: Using these classes, all response `StatusCodes` above `399` are treated as exceptions (why? long story :). You must always have a `Try/Catch` logic in place that can handle an exception (possibly, specific exceptions) and act on it. Log the rest, eventually. Or notify. Or both. A Log, here, can be useful to purge a list of URIs if some of them have an abit of missing a response or acting *weird* (as asking to downgrade the TLS protocol in the handshake or switch to HTTP without errors).